# Is it always possible to make both pieces connected?

Tags: connectedness, path-connected

Inside a path-connected set, there is a path-connected subset (**G**reen) whose complement (**P**ink) is disconnected:

[image]

We would like to move a small piece from G to P, such that both of them are path-connected:

[image]

Is it always possible?

Formally, given two sets $G,P$ such that $G$ and $G\cup P$ are path-connected, and given $\epsilon>0$, we would like to find a subset $H\subseteq G$, such that:

- The area of $H$ is at most $\epsilon$;
- $G\setminus H$ is path-connected;
- $P\cup H$ is path-connected.

Is this always possible? If not, what conditions on $G,P$ are required to make it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a counterexample, let
$$ G = \{0\}\times[0,1] \cup (0,1) \times ([0,1]\setminus \mathbb Q) \\
P = \{1\}\times([0,1]\setminus \mathbb Q) $$

$G\cup P$ is path-connected, but the only way to connect two different points of $P$ is to go all the way down to the $x$-axis, then horizontally and then up again. So $H$ has to be all of $G$, which has area (that is, Lebesgue measure) $1$.

---

Or, for a less pathological example, consider

$$ G = (\mathbb R\setminus \{0\})\times (0,\infty) \cup \{(0,0)\} \\
   P = (\mathbb R\setminus \{0\})\times (-\infty,0) $$

---

Or, nicer yet,

$$ G = \mathbb R \times (0,1) \\
   P = \mathbb R^2 \setminus G $$

Comment: Nice examples! What conditions can be added in order to make the claim true?

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi: I have trouble coming up with a nice sufficient condition, except for very blunt ones such as "$G$ in bounded by a piecewise smooth Jordan curve".

Comment: Why is "G in bounded by a piecewise smooth Jordan curve" sufficient?

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi: Because (I think) then declaring a sufficiently thing strip of uniform width along the entire boundary of $G$ to be $H$ will work to connect the pink parts without breaking $G$ into several pieces.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Henning Makholm's counterexamples, here's an example where $G$ has finite area and $P$ is open.  Let $P = \{(x,y) : |y| < |x|\}$.  Choose $f(x)$ to be a non-negative function with $f(0) = 0$, $f(x) > 0$ for $x \not= 0$ and $0 < \int_{0}^\infty f\;dx < \infty$.  Then, let
$$G = \{(x,y) : |x| \le |y| \le |x| + f(|x|)\}.$$
The area of $G$, $m(G)$, is equal to $4\int_0^\infty f\;dx$.  If $H$ is a subset of $G$ such that $H \cup P$ is path connected, then $(0,0) \in H$.  On the other hand, $G \setminus \{ (0,0)\} $ has four connected components of area $\int_0^\infty f\;dx$, so $H$ must contain three of these components, and $m(H) \ge 3\int_0^\infty f\;dx = \frac{3}{4}m(G) > 0$.